# show the list of files selected from different directories and ability to remove the files

Tags: html, angularjs, spring

I am trying to attach some files (zero/single/multiple) and send them as attachments to an email using ANGULARJS and spring.

One thing noticed is when selecting the files from multiple directories only the recently selected file is shown and previous selected file is not shown. How can I show all the files selected by the user from different directories too and give the ability to delete the file (all files or one file) before submitting the form.

Demo:http://plnkr.co/edit/M3f0TxHNozRxFEnrqyiF?p=preview

html:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
TO: <input type="text" name="to" id="to"  ng-model="to" required ></input><br>
Subject : <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject"  ng-model="subject"></input>
<br>Attachment:  <input type="file" ng-file-model="files" multiple /> <br>
 <p ng-repeat="file in files">
  {{file.name}}
</p>
<textarea rows="20" maxlength=35000 name="message"  ng-model="message" ></textarea>
<button type="button" ng-click="upload()">Send</button>
</body>
```

js:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.files = []; 
  $scope.upload=function(){
    alert($scope.files.length+" files selected ... Write your Code to send the mail"); 

  };
});


app.directive('ngFileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.ngFileModel);
            var isMultiple = attrs.multiple;
            var modelSetter = model.assign;
            element.bind('change', function () {
                var values = [];
                angular.forEach(element[0].files, function (item) {
                    var value = {
                       // File Name 
                        name: item.name,
                        //File Size 
                        size: item.size,
                        //File URL to view 
                        url: URL.createObjectURL(item),
                        // File Input Value 
                        _file: item
                    };
                    values.push(value);
                });
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    if (isMultiple) {
                        modelSetter(scope, values);
                    } else {
                        modelSetter(scope, values[0]);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The default browser behavior is showing currently selected files, to cahnge that you've to customize that filed. And also, I saw your custom directive code, it doesn't allow to select multiple files from different directories. 
So, what you can do is, create another scope variable & every time user selects file/files you push those files to this array. In this way you've have set of all selected files from same/different directories and then you can have delete functionality over each file which's ultimately going to be updated.
Updated html view part:

```
Attachment:  <input type="file" ng-file-model="files" multiple /><br>
<p ng-repeat="file in filesToUpload track by $index">
    {{file.name}} <span class="delete-file" ng-click="deleteFile($index)">X</span>
</p>
```

And for this new array update directive scope.$apply part as:

```
scope.$apply(function () {
    if (isMultiple) {
        modelSetter(scope, values);
    } else {
        modelSetter(scope, values[0]);
    }
    if(values){
      scope.filesToUpload = scope.filesToUpload.concat(values);
    }
});
```

In controller have deleteFile function as:

```
$scope.deleteFile = function(index){
  $scope.filesToUpload.splice(index, 1);
};
```

[**Working Demo Example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/mdIVj5zwdOHWjT9Jhqdc?p=preview)

Now user'll be able to delete files anytime. But the input field will still show the last selected file/files and after deleting particular file also it'll not change its status so for that you can just hide field by opacity: 0; css & then create customized Upload button & from that trigger click on actual hidden file input element.

**Update**: Check this update of same code with custom upload button:
[**Plunker Example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/uGZGFj28717wPhUg9iV3?p=preview)

Comment: Please find the demo with some of your code  http://plnkr.co/edit/ch4fVz7iXmJRPthvCsQt?p=preview . I am facing issue when I have selected multiple files and clicked on send button, the file object is printing as [object Object] instead of [object File]. When user selects the file I'm printing the object in getFiles(..) method where it is perfectly showing [object File]. How can I get the object to be printed as [object File] in $scope.upload(..) which is called when user click on Send button.. [object File] allows to read file information at server unlike as [object Object]..

Comment: @user8373379 Code is working fine. Why are you alerting everywhere? They're all objects & that's what it'll show in alert! If you really want to see what's inside of those objects just do console.log or debug the code in chrome dev tools. Check this one: http://plnkr.co/edit/9Enx6BOeDJYs1jCNSS5J?p=preview I've logged the values..(on click of send check the console)

Comment: @user8373379 Also check the same thing in the custom upload button example: https://plnkr.co/edit/uGZGFj28717wPhUg9iV3?p=preview On send check the console for the filesToBeUploaded. This's best solution for your case